# Is there any COM library for Java that works well?

Tags: java, windows, com

I'm rewriting a script that uses COM to automate a windows application, and I'd like to rewrite it in Java. The thing is, the COM libraries seem a little outdated, and I don't want to waste time with code that doesn't work. Is there anything you tried and worked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at [**JACOB**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)? Last updated June 8, 2009.

> JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows
>   you to call COM Automation components
>   from Java. It uses JNI to make native
>   calls to the COM libraries. JACOB runs
>   on x86 and x64 environments supporting
>   32 bit and 64 bit JVMs

Comment: I can also recommend this - have used it in several projects, and it works perfectly (just be sure you release references in finally blocks - we get lazy having the GC!). I will say that true COM programming (which Jacob exposes) is not for the uninitiated. Take the time to find a good book on the subject before trying to delve into Jacob.